# How to assign new class after a button/link is clicked(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add new CSS class to HTML body but only after a button/link is clicked. I have included the code along with some errors information.

I have already created a function that can trigger an alert after the button/link is clicked. it's working perfectly but the ".classList.add " method/option is not taking any effects.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .addBGoverlay {background-color: gray;}

    .bG {background-color: white;}
    </style>
</head>
<body class="BG">
    <a class="dash-menu mega-menu-link " role="button" href="#"><span class="mega-indicator"> navButtn</span></a>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var X = document.getElementsByClassName('dash-menu');
    var xLength = X.length;
    var bg = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

    function startAction() {
    alert('This a popUp');
    bg.classList.add("addBGoverlay");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < xLength; i++) {
    X[i].addEventListener('click', startAction, false);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I inspect it in chrome it gives me an error  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.startAction" and the below line is highlited in yellow color "bg.classList.add("addBGoverlay");"

Comment: Enclose it in window.onload()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByTagName() method will give you a collection of DOM elements. Since this collection don't have a classList property it will fail.
You can fix it by using the below code

```
bg[0].classList.add("addBGoverlay");
```

You can also use **document.body** instead of **document.getElementsByTagName('body')**. First one (document.body) give you the body object and second one will give you a collection object

For switch to previous state

**Approach 1**

```
function startAction() {

    let body = document.body ;
    if(body.classList.contans("addBGoverlay")){ // body.classList.contans() method will give a Boolean return value
       body.classList.remove("addBGoverlay");
   }else{
       body.classList.add("addBGoverlay");
   }

}
```

**Approach 2**

```
var hasBGOverlay = false;
var body = document.body ;
function startAction() {

    if(hasBGOverlay){ 
           body.classList.remove("addBGoverlay");
    }else{
           body.classList.add("addBGoverlay");
    }
    hasBGOverlay  = !hasBGOverlay; // In each call state variable value will update with inverse value

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you. This solves the problem. can you suggest another thing, How can I undo it or back to the previous settings when the user clicks again on the button/link.?

Comment: @dream world you can achieve it in different ways. Either you can keep a bool state variable and check the state before add or remove class to the body or you can use the contains method for classList property. I will update my code with some example

Answer (score 0):

Try with Add ID attribute to body tag.

ie:

```
<body class="bg" id="dg_body">
```

js

```
var bg = document.getElementById('dg_body');
```

and update css order :

```
.bG {background-color: white;}
.addBGoverlay {background-color: gray;}
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from :

```
bg.classList.add("addBGoverlay");
```

To:

```
bg.className += "addBGoverlay";
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing it under window.load should solve it as it ensures that the DOM is ready before you try to fetch the elements.

```js
window.onload(function() {
  var X = document.getElementsByClassName('dash-menu');
  var xLength = X.length;
  var bg = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

  function startAction() {
    alert('This a popUp');
    bg.classList.add("addBGoverlay");
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < xLength; i++) {
    X[i].addEventListener('click', startAction, false);
  }
});
```

```css
.addBGoverlay {
  background-color: gray;
}

.bG {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="dash-menu mega-menu-link " role="button" href="#"><span class="mega-indicator">navButtn</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
var bg = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

This will fix the error.

Comment: this works too :). can you suggest another thing, How can I undo it or back to the previous settings when the user clicks again on the button/link.?

Answer (score 0):

It must resolve your's problem.

> you no need to get an element for the body. Document have that one. So
>   just concatenate the new class.

```
function startAction() {
    alert('This a popUp');
    document.body.className += "addBGoverlay";
}
```